# Parar Menu scroll em certa resolução

Tags: jquery, css, menu, layout-responsivo, addclass

Tenho um menu que desce juntamente com o scroll. Utilizei Jquery para adicionar atributos css para que isso ocorra.
Não quero que isto ocorra quando o site tiver menos que 768px de width. Aí que ele fique parado

Media queries não me ajudaram a resolver por conta desses atributos serem adicionados independente de resolução. Então tentei o seguinte:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(window).width() < 760)
     {
        $('#menu').css({'position' : 'absolute'});
     }
 });
```

Ou isso

```
$(function() {
if ( $(window).width() < 760) {     
  $('#menu').css({'position' : 'relative'});
}
});
```

Mas não rolou em ambos casos.
Sou novato em Jquery. Como complementar esse código para que funcione?
Estou indo pelo caminho certo?

Este é o código que faz meu menu scroll

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function()
{
var topo = $('#topo').height(); // altura do topo
var rodape = $('#rodape').height(); // altura do rodape
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // qto foi rolado a barra
var tamPagina = $(document).height(); // altura da p?gina

if(scrollTop > topo){
  $('#menu').css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : '0'});
}else{
  $('#menu').css({'position' : 'relative', 'margin-top' : 0});
}
});
});
```

Comment: É `absolute` mesmo? Não seria `fixed`?

Comment: Eu colei o código absolute por engano, aqui eu tentei o fixed mesmo mas não parou o scroll do menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o `$(window).resize()` para o `jQuery` detectar que a tela foi redimensionada

Exemplo:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
      if ( $(this).width() < 760) {     
        $('#menu').css({'position' : 'relative'});
      }
    }
});
```

### Atualização

Depois da sua atualização, imagino que o que você esteja querendo algo parecido com isso:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        var topo = $('#topo').height(); // altura do topo
        var rodape = $('#rodape').height(); // altura do rodape
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // qto foi rolado a barra
        var tamPagina = $(document).height(); // altura da p?gina

        if($(window).width() > 760 && scrollTop > topo){
          $('#menu').css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : '0'});
        } else{
          $('#menu').css({'position' : 'relative', 'margin-top' : 0});
        }
    });
});
```

Pois ele deve atender duas condições: A tela deve ser maior que `760px` e deve atender à condição desejada quando o `$(window).scrollTop()` for maior que o tamanho do topo

Comment: Eu tentei implementar isto mas não correspondeu ao que necessito. Vou incrementar o código que coloquei acima talvez fique mais claro.

Comment: Isso Wallace fucionou do jeito que imaginei. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim, porque, se você não quer que funcione se for menor que 760, utilize o `>` na condição.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(window).width() > 760)
         {
            $('#menu').css({'position' : 'absolute'});
         }
     });
```

Comment: Obrigado miguel

Answer (score 1):

É melhor manipular classes ao invés dos elementos diretamente.
Você pode iniciar esse menu com uma classe responsável por mantê-lo fixo no topo e então usar Javascript <sup><sup>(JQuery)</sup></sup> somente para verificar se essa classe deve ou não ser removida dependendo da largura de `$(window)`.

Já para tratar o redimensionamento, use `resize`. Basta verificar o largura da janela e se o elemento possui a classe que mantém o menu fixo. Exemplo:

```
// js

$(function(){   
    if($(window).width() < 768){
        $('.menu').removeClass('is-fixed');
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   var menu = $('.menu');

   /*
    * Se for menor que a largura que você definiu e...
    * Se o elemento possuir a classe 'is-fixed', então...
    * ela é removida.
    * 
    * Do contrário a classe é inserida.
    */
   if($(window).width() < 768 && menu.hasClass('is-fixed')){
       menu.removeClass('is-fixed');
   } else {
       menu.addClass('is-fixed');
   }
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxn/gasz5unj/embedded/result/)

<sup>Precisei colocar no JSFiddle porque no StackOverflow não funciona a função `resize`.</sup>

Comment: Mas aí a parte do scroll fica prejudicada, pois ele quer que o efeito ocorra quando o scroll atual for maior que a div do topo

Comment: @WallaceMaxters respondido para [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/49987/1) pergunta.

Comment: ok ................. :)